# [IDA plugin]How to set variables type in python api?

Tags: python, plugins, ida

I am now working on a IDA plugin development.  but I got some problem on this. I need your help .

Here is the situation:

- I used the hexray plugin to get a decompiled function like this: c_func=idaapi.decompile(0x1234).
- after getting c_func object,  I want to manipulate on this object, like changing type of some lvars, and then obain the updated pseudo C-code.  but I do not know how to do this. There is rarely few reference on this topic.

Could anyone help me on this?

Actually, what I want to do is just a simulation of "Set lvar Type" in pseudocode window of IDA . If a proper type is set for some lvars, the hex-ray decompiler will automatic change the pseudo-C code according to the new type.

I want to do this by calling SDK APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
c=idaapi.decompile(func.startEA)
for v in c.lvars:
    if name==v.name:
        v.set_lvar_type(...)  or v.set_final_lvar_type(...) or v.force_lvar_type(...)
```

See here: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/classlvar__t.shtml#a2963a6281d004d2868728ec8c8c04fd6

You can create t_info and use the deserialize function in order to set the type.

Good luck!